# Must run removeChild() twice in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, removechild

I'm baffled over this one.
I'm creating a lightbox-style div with its own dynamic content, like so:

```
//ADD LIGHTBOX DIV
var DG_lightbox = document.createElement('div');
DG_lightbox.className = "DG_lightbox";
DG_lightbox.id= "DG_lightbox";
document.body.appendChild(DG_lightbox);
//ADD MAIN CONTENT DIV
var DG_contentbox = document.createElement('div');
DG_contentbox.className = "DG_contentbox";
DG_contentbox.id= "DG_contentbox";
DG_lightbox.appendChild(DG_contentbox);
```

There's a lot more content, obviously, but it's all added to the DG_lightbox div in the same way.
The lightbox has a close button that *should* look like this:

```
function closeDG(){
DG_lightbox.parentNode.removeChild(DG_lightbox);
return false;
window.location.hash = "";  
}
```

It works great in IE and Chrome, but in Firefox it doesn't seem to completely get rid of the object. Every ***second*** time the lightbox is created, some of the content appears to not initialize correctly, and when closed again, the browser has to think about it before it gets removed (as if twice the content is being removed). After that, it works normally again, until a ***fourth*** time.

So if I use `removeChild()` twice in `closeDG()` I don't have this problem, but the page refreshes, as if `return false` weren't working for the second method (duplicate `return false` does nothing).

I'd love to be able to use only one instance of `removeChild()`, but am willing to live with the duplicate method as long as I can prevent the page from refreshing when they're called.

The webpage is here: http://www.apennydreadful.com
Click "Chapters > Begin here" to see the script in action.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

~gyz

*UPDATE*
It appears that adding a second `removeChild` is *not* what's getting it to work. Instead, since the second `removeChild` is causing the code to skip the `return false`, the page refreshes, refreshing the code as well ... so the recurring error on every other click never gets reached, but it's still there.
So, again, I'm at a loss. Even if I empty the div using `$("#DG_lightbox").empty();` before using `$("#DG_lightbox").remove();` the result is the same.

Comment: Your link gave a 503 and the code you pasted does not allow us to tell how your contexts allows closeDG to see DG_lightbox.

Comment: Odd, www.apennydreadful.com is working for me.
I'm also not sure what you mean about context allowing closeDG to see DG_lightbox ... the DG_lightbox variable should refer directly to the created object. I'm probably misunderstanding your comment.

Comment: I tried making a jsfiddle for the above, but it doesn't seem to want to work in fiddle (something about the return false creating a post request error - I don't get it), but the code works in a regular html: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gyzhor/2tbRg/6/

Comment: When you call `removeChild` a second time, it throws, so the `return false` is never reached, which is why you get the page reload.  It's hard to say what's going wrong with the case when you don't call `removeChild` twice, because that's not what the page is doing right now.  Could you restore it back to only calling it once in Firefox, please?

Comment: Sure thing, Boris. I've updated the page to only call removeChild once. If you check out the "begin here" page two times, you'll see that the next page arrow doesn't appear the second time, and it'll take longer to close.

Comment: Looks like my host is having network issues, accounting for that 503 Joseph encountered earlier (which I've gotten some of today as well). Hopefully that'll be cleared up soon.

Comment: Okay, site it back up. It's become pretty clear that the reason for the duplicate removeChild() is buried somewhere else in the code, so I'll keep hunting for it. In the mean time, if anyone can come up with a way to keep the `return false` from getting ignored, it'd love to have it as a temporary work-around. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its not just Firefox where this happens as I have seen the same problem in Chrome. The usual cause is the presence of unexpected text nodes. The following HTML will fail in exactly the way you describe:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Replace Test</title>
</head>
<body> 
<p id="demo">Click the button to replace </p> 
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button> 
<script>
var cnt = 1;
var para=document.createElement("p");
var innerDiv =document.createElement("div");
var node=document.createTextNode("If original text is still showing, click button again, count ="+cnt);
para.appendChild(node);
para.id = "p1";
innerDiv.appendChild(para);

function myFunction()
{ 
  var  target=document.getElementById("foo");
  target.appendChild(innerDiv); 
  var current = target.firstChild; 
  target.removeChild(target.firstChild);
  cnt = cnt +1;
  window.console.log("btn pressed, cnt="+cnt); 
}
</script>
<div id="foo">
   <div id="bar"> 
    <p>This is text that should vanish when the button is clicked.</p> 
   </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the "bar" div element is not really the first child node of "foo". There
is a pair of text nodes, one before "bar" and one after, each containing a carriage return. On the other hand, if the HTML is changed to

```
<div id="foo"><div id="bar"> 
  <p>This is text that should vanish when the button is clicked.</p> 
</div></div>
```

the script works correctly. The carriage returns in "bar" don't matter.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm using the firstChild() method. In fact, if I clear the div entirely before I try to remove it, I get the same result (suing something like this):

`function clodeDG(){
jQuery("#DG_lightbox").empty();
jQuery("#DG_lightbox").remove();
}`

Comment: One thing that tripped me up when I encountered a similar problem is the distinction between Nodes and Elements. The carriage returns, being text, instantiate as text nodes, not Elements. I believe your remove() and empty() operations will clear out the elements but leave intact any nodes in your DOM structure. I found that using my browser's debugger to examine the document helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So I've managed to fix my problem. Seems like a pretty simple issue not really related to my initial question, actually.  The dynamic content inside of the div I was attempting to remove was defined inside of the same function that created that parent div.  Something like this:

```
function clickThis(){
var DG_lightbox = document.createElement('div');
DG_lightbox.className = "DG_lightbox";
DG_lightbox.id= "DG_lightbox";
document.body.appendChild(DG_lightbox);

var DG_tooltip = document.createElement('div');
DG_tooltip.className = "DG_tooltip";
DG_tooltip.id= "DG_tooltip";
DG_tooltip.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
DG_lightbox.appendChild(DG_tooltip);
};
```

These elements removed and re-created themselves fine on the next link-click in Chrome and IE, but Firefox was not having it.  Not sure why. Maybe someone more knowledgeable could explain.
Anyways, I defined the vars globally and now everything's right as rain.

Thanks for all the assistance as always,
~gyz